# Steps to create AWS snapshot automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337936/automating-ebs-snapshot-from-its-instance-itself) but its not clear the steps to follow to create a automatic aws snapshot from a EBS volume.

In the [AWS documentaion](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html) they talked about creating a new Snapshot but not how to do it automatically?

Can anyone tell be the steps to make snapshot automatically on regular basis?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic? Use AWS CLI or API to create a snapshot. And you call it periodically. AWS does not provide a way to create snapshots periodically.

Comment: i mean every day it should create a backup itself

Comment: Amazon does not provide automatic snapshot. It is a simple one line entry in the crontab is you have AWS CLI installed. Or few lines of python script [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029547/aws-ami-automatic-snapshots)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API and create a windows task locally on your computer to run this command daily or weekly.

for example

ec2-create-snapshot vol-xxxxxxxxx --description "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this versatile script https://github.com/evannuil/aws-snapshot-tool